# How do integrate SabreAMF with PHP

Tags: amf

Any help on this? Examples from project site are not working..

Comment: Are you getting any error messages?

Comment: I am getting any error, actually don't know how to debug.

Comment: I am trying to integrate Flash with PHP, was not able to find any examples :(